# Cannot update id - id not updatable

Tags: c#, database, parameters

I try to update my info data (in access database) on employee table, but I get this error that says **cannot update id - id not updatable**

Lets say I have this employee

ID : 1

Name : Mark

LastName : Jonhson

Age : 33

I write update statement, in case I want to change his info in future, ...let's say

ID : 1

Name : Mark

LastName : Markson

Age: 34

**My code** What did I do wrong and how do I update/edit my data

```
private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Employee set ID = @ID, Name = @Name, LastName = @LastName, User_name = @User_name, Password = @Password, E_mail = @E_mail, Address = @Address";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", ID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", lastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_name", userName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", pass.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@E_mail", eMail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", address.Text);


            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("User updated!");
            myConncetion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `WHERE` to your command text.If you don't it,all of your records will be change.I think you want this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Employee SET Name = @Name, LastName = @LastName, User_name = @User_name, Password = @Password, E_mail = @E_mail, Address = @Address WHERE ID = @ID";
```

Comment: it still gives me the same error, when i write it like this =/

Comment: actually without the **SET** it gives me syntax error in update statement

Comment: sorryy, it's my mistake :-) try again

Comment: Another error ---> **The value of at least one of the required parameters has not been determined**

Comment: instead of `cmd.Parameters.Add` try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` method

Comment: Do i need to delete SET ID = @ID in the update statement and cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", ID.text); or not?

Comment: delete just  SET ID = @ID ,leave other

Comment: Now it says, Data updated, ...but the user still has the same username as before. How is that possible?

Comment: I don't know,maybe you didn't change your user name,or you type the wrong id.try to execute same query in sql server

Comment: When i click on User, it fills all the textboxes on it's own. I just changed the Username from Mark to Markk and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your "ID" is not just a piece of data, but the table primary key too. In that case you should **never** update that.

The primary key is meant to be immutable, not only because it uniquely identifies a record in the DB, also all other tables will reference this column though `foreign keys`, which will either break or leave orphaned rows everywhere. Additionally, what's the purpose of updating it? The user is not even aware of its existence, since it's only part of the internal DB structure that keeps integrity, nothing more.

In short, don't try it.

If you **really** want to update it, the column should not be autogenerated, as the DB engine most likely will catch your error and prevent it.

Comment: So i just delete it and delete the where statement?

Comment: Yes, just delete it from the `SET` part, but the `WHERE` clause as others have said is correct and important. The ID column is a good candidate for use in the `WHERE` precisely, as it can identify the row uniquely.

Comment: ok thanks, but somehow it doesn't update my info. I don't get any errors, it's says successfully updated, but the info is still the same.

I've made no mistakes because texboxes get filled on it's own when i press on user id in datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, `ID` is an auto-generated primary key in the database. You cannot update that.

Actually, your UPDATE statement would update all records in the table, since it is lacking a WHERE clause. This is very dangerous. You should specify the record you want to update in your WHERE clause, and when possible, reference it via the primary key:

```
UPDATE Employee Name = @Name, LastName = @LastName, User_name = @User_name, Password = @Password, E_mail = @E_mail, Address = @Address 
WHERE Id = @Id;
```